# List of Data.Frames with uneven oberservations to single Data.Frame

Tags: r

[image: Bland.Altman.List]

I do have a list consisting of multiple data.frames that I would like to combine to one single data.frame removing NAs column-wise.

[a link]https://quickfileshare.org/Xmv/bland.altman.csv

```
bland.altman.df<-bind_rows(bland.altman.list)
```

gives me back a data.frame that includes what I actually would like, however still full of NAs. One solution could now be that I can extract single columns and na.omit() them and saving them to a new data frame. 
Is there a more elegant way to deal with this problem?

As columns are of uneven length, cbind.fill will leave back some NAs. I am well aware of this. However, it would be by far less than what I have now. 
The aim is to get a data.frame with as little NAs as possible.

Comment: have you tryed `do.call("cbind", bland.altman.list)`? or `do.call("merge", bland.altman.list)`?

Comment: take a look at `plyr::rbind.fill`